# ‘Forgot Wallet’

Tags: wallet-recovery, funds

Transferred BTC from Crypto dot com app to blockchain dot com wallet. Somehow managed to “forget wallet” in blockchain. Have my 12 words and tried to recover but no luck. It was mentioned to me that imported addresses are not backed up.

Any way to know if the wallet was an imported address (other than it’s not showing up). AND is there a way to recover it? Pretty unversed when it comes to this stuff so the more laymans terms the better!

Answer (score 1):

If Blockchaindotcom follows the Bitcoin standard of BIP32, then the 12 words should allow you to recover your funds on any wallet. You can try downloading Bluewallet and recovering the wallet there.

You do not need to "import addresses" to access your funds, as long as you have your private keys (which are derived from the 12 words).

Comment: what meant by imported address blockchaindotcom support told me when I used private key I deleted currency probably b/c imported address- not safe from backup.
Been successful at creating new wallet ID using private key. Neither website or app will fully load- very glitchy. I have another account (completely separate) has absolutely no issues. 
My question what is imported address? How would I know if that’s the location my BTC was in? 
I created blockchaindotcom account and sent funds to the wallet created. I purchased/sent funds from cryptodotcom- does that mean it’s an imported address?